# There is a way to get all the option values in the SELECT TAG without an ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

do you know if there is a way to take all the values in the OPTION VALUE included in a SELECT?
i Will show you an example, I have this code:

```
<SELECT onChange="chData(this,this.value)"> 
<OPTION VALUE=MIPS1 >MIPS
<OPTION VALUE=MSU1 >MSU
<OPTION VALUE=PERCEN1 >% CEC
<OPTION VALUE=NUMGCP1 >nCPU
</SELECT>
```

I only know the first value which is MIPS1, and I need to take the other values. The is a way to write that if I know the first MIPS1 I will search for the other values Included from the ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How many select tags do you have in your html?

Comment: Please explain in more detail when you need to do this...inside `chData()` when it gets called? What is expected result?

Comment: @charlietfl I think Dana is trying to pass the selected value when the onChange ecent occurs.

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan makes it simple if that is true since `this` is the `<select>`...but it may not be the case at all which is why I asked

Comment: Hi, thanks for the amswers. I have different SELECT tags in my page which are related to different tables, because in each table I have a combo box. The point is that I cannot ad an ID in the select because I cannot modify the code that create the html page. What I expect to do  is to create an array with the OPTION VALUE i have (in this case: MIPS1,MSU1,PERCEN1 and NUMGCP1). It's true that I don'have an ID, but I know if I have MIPS1 or MU1..so i want to take all the nearest option values included in the SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows how you can do this. The Jquery is fully commented.

Let me know if it isn't what you were hoping for.

---

## Demo

```js
// Create array
var options = [];

// Load option value you're looking for into a variable
var search_term = "MIPS1";

// Find option with known value, travel up DOM tree to select and then find all options within it
$("option[value='" + search_term + "']").closest("select").find("option").each(function() {

  // Add values to array
  options.push($(this).val());

});

// Print the array
console.log(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT onChange="chData(this,this.value)">
  <OPTION VALUE=MIPS1>MIPS
  <OPTION VALUE=MSU1>MSU
  <OPTION VALUE=PERCEN1>% CEC
  <OPTION VALUE=NUMGCP1>nCPU
</SELECT>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for :) Thanksss ! The only thing I need to change is the fact that MIPS1 should be a variable because it is dynamic (it should be MIPS1 but it can assumes also other values). What I need to do in order to pass it as a variable? Thanksss

Comment: Updated to search using a variable that you can set as you need to. Glad it worked! Please upvote / accept the answer if you're happy.

Comment: I use in this way to have a variable:

Comment: // Create array
    var options = [];

    // Find option with known value, travel up DOM tree to select and then find all 
    options within it
    $("option[value="+table_id+"]").closest("select").find("option").each(function() {

  // Add values to array
      options.push($(this).val());

    });

Comment: $("option[value="+table_id+"]")

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `<select>` element that has an option with a specific value using something like this:

```
const select = document.querySelector('option[value=MIPS1]').closest('select');
```

Once you have the `<select>` element you can retrieve it's options using something like this:

```
const options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
```

Or:

```
const options = select.options;
```

As @charlietfl mentioned, `.closest` is not supported by all browsers, instead of that, you could use `.parentElement`.

Comment: Note IE doesn't support `closest()`

Comment: @charlietfl it does if jQuery is used (tagged)

Comment: @mplungjan jQuery `closest()` is not the same as native `Element.closest()` used in answer.

Comment: I know - it was also a hint to Titus

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version

```js
var opt = "MIPS1";
const $sel = $("option[value='"+opt+"']").parent()
const options = $("option",$sel).map(function() { return this.value }).get()
console.log(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SELECT onChange="chData(this,this.value)">
  <OPTION VALUE=MIPS1>MIPS
  <OPTION VALUE=MSU1>MSU
  <OPTION VALUE=PERCEN1>% CEC
  <OPTION VALUE=NUMGCP1>nCPU
</SELECT>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for :) Thanksss ! The only thing I need to change is the fact that MIPS1 should be a variable because it is dynamic (it should be MIPS1 but it can assumes also other values). What I need to do in order to pass it as a variable? Thanksss

Comment: value='"+var+"'

Comment: @Dana if this is what you were looking for, why do you accept another less elegant suggestion?

Comment: at the beginning i did confusion between the answers, I used his answer by I answered to you. I verified that both worked perfctly so at the end i used his answer because he answered me fater to one of my last doubt. Just for this. There is no reason,:)thanks

Comment: Maybe someone knows why i cannot ask another question? The site says that I bypass my question limit -.-'

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get: selected value, selected text and all the values in the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      var option = $('option[value="MIPS1"]');
      var select = option.parent();
      var value = $(select).find(":selected").val();
      var optionName = $(select).find(":selected").text();
      var result = "value = "+value+"\noption name = "+optionName+"\nall values = ";
      $(select).each(function(){
          result+=($(this).text()+" ");
     });
      console.log(result);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select> 
<option value=MIPS1 >MIPS</option>
<option value=MSU1 >MSU</option>
<option value=PERCEN1 >% CEC</option>
<option value=NUMGCP1 >nCPU</option>
</select>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: This is not at all what was asked

Comment: Ain't this displaying the values in the options tag?

Comment: It not showing all the options in a select that has an option with value MIPS1 - which is the question asked,

Comment: I posted it for his convenience . In case he wants to find what value he has selected.

Comment: Look at the alert in top of your screen. It will say `all values = ` followed by the values in the dropdown :)

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Still, it will fail if there is any other select on the page - and not only a select with an option with value MIPS1

Comment: I changed it to console.log for convenience. I will make an edit to display the details of the first dropdown.

Comment: _I only know the first value which is MIPS1, and I need to take the other values_

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea not to give id to your html element in the first place, however if you need to do it that way, then the code below assumes you have only one select tag on your page.

```
let select = document.querySelector('select');
options = select.childNodes.filter((c) => c.tagName==='OPTION')
             .map((o) => o.value);
console.log(options)
```